# how to fix Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/clients/client0/web2/web/app/code/Mirasvit/Search/Block/Result.php

```
 * @return IndexInterface
 */
public function getFirstMatchedIndex()
{
    foreach ($this->getIndices() as $index) {
        if (($index->getData('store_id') == false
            || $index->getData('store_id') == $this->getCurrentStore()->getId())
        ) {
            return $index;
        }
    }

    return $this->getIndices()[0];
}
```

Comment: can you print this code `$this->getIndices()` to see what data are you getting? also, share a screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code instead

```
* @return IndexInterface
 */
public function getFirstMatchedIndex()
{
    foreach ($this->getIndices() as $index) {
        if (($index->getData('store_id') == false
            || $index->getData('store_id') == $this->getCurrentStore()->getId())
        ) {
            return $index;
        }
    }

    if(count($this->getIndices()) > 0){
        return $this->getIndices()[0];
    }
    return array();
}
```

This should work.

Comment: it show me a blank page not any result

Comment: After using above code your error should resolve. The blank page is causing from the code where `getFirstMatchedIndex()` function calling, you need to debug that

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're calling an index that does not exist in the array.

```
public function getFirstMatchedIndex()
{
    // Return empty array if no indices.
    if (!$this->getIndices()) {
       return [];
    }

    foreach ($this->getIndices() as $index) {
        if ($index->getData('store_id') === false) {
           return $index;
        } elseif ($index->getData('store_id') === $this->getCurrentStore()->getId()) {
           return $index;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Return indice at index 0 or empty array if index 
     * does not exist.
     */
    return $this->getIndices()[0] ?? [];
}
```

Comment: it show me a blank page now

Comment: not show me a result after search in searchbar